# get alert when count in a column exceeds 100

Tags: sql

I have a table in which there is a column called "message type". I want to get an alert when count of records in  message type column exceeds 100

Comment: What SQL server are you using? You need to provide more details, in order someone help you.

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1523/how-to-setup-sql-server-alerts-and-email-operator-notifications/ you should provide more information like the version of SQL Server you're using and what you have tried so far..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres there is LISTEN/NOTIFY. Oracle has a "change notification" feature, other DBMS might have different solutions.

Comment: The count of records in the column??? There is a number of records in a *table*, but not in a *column*. Or are you saying that you want to count records where message type is not null only? Or do you want a maximum of 100 records *per* message type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
((SELECT Count(*) FROM table) >= '100')
THEN 'ALERT'
ELSE null
END
```

Create a job that runs every 10 seconds/5 seconds or what ever and put in the above query and get it to email if there are results.